# Уменьшение формы при сужении экрана

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Не могу разобраться, хочу чтобы на брекпоинте 320-768 форма сужалась и выглядела посередине,но верстка ломается,что не так?

```css
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #1B2473;
  color: #787878;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 20px;
}

.form {
  width: 600px;
  padding: 26px 46px 26px 45px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.form__title {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 17px;
}

.form__group {}

.form__input_mg-bottom-13 {
  margin-bottom: 13px;
}

.form__input_mg-bottom-16 {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.form__label-input {
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 100%;
}

.form__input {
  width: 509px;
  height: 49px;
  border: 2px solid #787878;
  color: #787878;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
  font-size: 28px;
}

.form__input::placeholder {
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 129%;
  color: #cccccc;
}

.form__label-checkbox {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 114%;
  margin-bottom: 52px;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.form__checkbox {
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border: 2px solid #787878;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.form__btn {
  width: 180px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 67%;
  background: #1A226B;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px 56px 18px 55px;
}

.form__btn:hover {
  background: #3e4588;
}

.form__button-block {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}


/* ------------- 320 - 768------------------------- */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .form {
    max-width: 728px;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .form__title {
    font-size: 60px;
    line-height: 83%;
    margin-bottom: 13px;
  }
  .form__group {}
  .form__label-input {
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 67%;
  }
  .form__input {
    max-width: 638px;
    margin-top: 8px;
  }
  .form__input::placeholder {
    color: #cccccc;
  }
  .form__label-checkbox {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 89%;
    margin-bottom: 64px;
  }
  .form__checkbox {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
  }
  .form__button-block {}
  .form__btn {
    max-width: 220px;
    min-height: 80px;
    padding: 32px 64px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <form action="#" class="form">

      <h1 class="form__title">Вход</h1>

      <div class="form__group">
        <label for="" class="form__label-input">Email</label>
        <input class="form__input form__input_mg-bottom-13" name="email" type="email" value="trubnikoviv84@gmail.com" disabled>
      </div>

      <div class="form__group">
        <label for="" class="form__label-input">Пароль</label>
        <input class="form__input form__input_mg-bottom-16" name="pass" type="password" placeholder="Введите пароль" required>
      </div>

      <div class="form__group">
        <label class="form__label-checkbox">
                    <input class="form__checkbox" name="checkbox" type="checkbox"> 
                    Я согласен получать обновления на почту
                </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form__button-block">
        <button class="form__btn" type="submit">Войти</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это происходит из-за использования фиксированного значения `width`

Пример

```css
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #1B2473;
  color: #787878;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 20px;
}

.form {
  max-width: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 26px 46px 26px 45px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.form__title {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 17px;
}

.form__group {}

.form__input_mg-bottom-13 {
  margin-bottom: 13px;
}

.form__input_mg-bottom-16 {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.form__label-input {
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 100%;
}

.form__input {
  max-width: 509px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 49px;
  border: 2px solid #787878;
  color: #787878;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
  font-size: 28px;
}

.form__input::placeholder {
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 129%;
  color: #cccccc;
}

.form__label-checkbox {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 114%;
  margin-bottom: 52px;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.form__checkbox {
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border: 2px solid #787878;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.form__btn {
  width: 180px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 67%;
  background: #1A226B;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px 56px 18px 55px;
}

.form__btn:hover {
  background: #3e4588;
}

.form__button-block {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}


/* ------------- 320 - 768------------------------- */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .form {
    max-width: 728px;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .form__title {
    font-size: 60px;
    line-height: 83%;
    margin-bottom: 13px;
  }
  .form__group {}
  .form__label-input {
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 67%;
  }
  .form__input {
    max-width: 638px;
    margin-top: 8px;
  }
  .form__input::placeholder {
    color: #cccccc;
  }
  .form__label-checkbox {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 89%;
    margin-bottom: 64px;
  }
  .form__checkbox {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
  }
  .form__button-block {}
  .form__btn {
    max-width: 220px;
    min-height: 80px;
    padding: 32px 64px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <form action="#" class="form">

      <h1 class="form__title">Вход</h1>

      <div class="form__group">
        <label for="" class="form__label-input">Email</label>
        <input class="form__input form__input_mg-bottom-13" name="email" type="email" value="trubnikoviv84@gmail.com" disabled>
      </div>

      <div class="form__group">
        <label for="" class="form__label-input">Пароль</label>
        <input class="form__input form__input_mg-bottom-16" name="pass" type="password" placeholder="Введите пароль" required>
      </div>

      <div class="form__group">
        <label class="form__label-checkbox">
                    <input class="form__checkbox" name="checkbox" type="checkbox"> 
                    Я согласен получать обновления на почту
                </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form__button-block">
        <button class="form__btn" type="submit">Войти</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, разобрался как это работает

Comment: @ИгорьТрубников не плохо бы отмечать ответы, которые вам помогли принятыми.

Comment: @ИгорьТрубников здесь не принято говорить "спасибо" в комментариях, вы можете оценить ответ и отметить его как принятый. [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) - более подробно раскрывает данную тему